# Using an ExternalProject download step with Ninja

Tags: cmake, ninja

This seems to be a common problem without a clear answer.

The situation is: we have a 3rd party dependency that we want to install *at build time* when building a target that depends on it. That's roughly:

```
ExternalProject_Add(target-ep
    DOWNLOAD_COMMAND <whatever>
    BUILD_COMMAND ""
    INSTALL_COMMAND ""
    CONFIGURE_COMMAND "")

add_library(target-imp STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(target-imp PROPERTIES
    INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES /path/to/install/include
    IMPORTED_LOCATION /path/to/install/lib/libwhatever.a)

add_library(target INTERFACE)
target_link_libraries(target INTERFACE target-imp)
add_dependencies(target target-ep)
```

(It takes three to tango here because of [cmake issue 15052](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/15052))

When using Unix Makefiles as the generator, this works great. Only installs dependencies on demand, all the builds work correctly.

However, on Ninja, this fails immediately with something like:

```
ninja: error: '/path/to/install/lib/libwhatever.a', needed by 'something', missing and no known rule to make it
```

This is because Ninja scans dependencies differently from Make (see [ninja issue 760](https://github.com/ninja-build/ninja/issues/760)). So what we have to do is actually tell Ninja that this external dependency exists. We can do that:

```
ExternalProject_Add(target-ep
    DOWNLOAD_COMMAND <whatever>
    BUILD_BYPRODUCTS /path/to/install/lib/libwhatever.a
    BUILD_COMMAND ""
    INSTALL_COMMAND ""
    CONFIGURE_COMMAND "")
```

Which unfortunately also fails with:

```
No build step for 'target-ep'ninja: error: mkdir(/path/to/install): Permission denied
```

This is because my download step has permissions to write to that path, but whatever `mkdir` command is being run by the underlying `add_custom_command()` from with `ExternalProject_Add()` does not.

So:

1. Is this possible *at all* with Ninja and CMake? (Version is not an issue, I can use the latest CMake if that solves the problem)
2. If there is some way to workaround with explicitly listing `BUILD_BYPRODUCTS`, is there a way to simply communicate that the entire directory that will get installed is a byproduct? That is, `/path/to/install/*` is a byproduct?

Comment: You've specified build byproducts, but given an empty build command. Does the error change if you make the build step do something?

Comment: @CraigScott I tried `echo hi` as a `BUILD_COMMAND`. My ninja output is now friendlier, but still dysfunctional.

Comment: I was only able to reproduce your original problem if I had a typo in my `IMPORTED_LOCATION`. I was not able to reproduce the permissions issue. Perhaps if you can post a minimal working example that reproduces your problem, we can investigate from there.

Comment: @CraigScott It's definitely not typo-related. This works great with make, and it works great if I pre-run the download step. It's hard to post a minimal example that demonstrates the permissions issue - requires having a permissions issue to begin with...

Answer (score 13):

The hidden `mkdir` step of `ExternalProject` (which all other steps directly or indirectly depend on) always tries to create the full set of directories, even if they won't be used. You can see this [here](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/blob/v3.11.2/Modules/ExternalProject.cmake#L2208-2223). For reference, it does this:

```
ExternalProject_Add_Step(${name} mkdir
  COMMENT "Creating directories for '${name}'"
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E make_directory ${source_dir}
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E make_directory ${binary_dir}
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E make_directory ${install_dir}
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E make_directory ${tmp_dir}
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E make_directory ${stamp_dir}${cfgdir}
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E make_directory ${download_dir}
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E make_directory ${log_dir}   # This one only since CMake 3.13
  )
```

The default install location on Unix systems is probably going to be `/usr/local`, so if you don't have write permissions to all of the directories it tries to make, then that may be related to your problem. I suggest you check the permissions of each of these locations and make sure they either already exist or are writable. Alternatively, you could specify an install directory that is local to the build tree so that even though it won't be used, it can at least always be created (see example further below).

If you use Ninja, it will be more rigorous in its dependency checking than make. You have `target-ep` doing the download that provides `libwhatever.a`, so you do need `BUILD_BYPRODUCTS` to tell Ninja that `target-ep` is what creates that file. As you've found out, if you don't then `target-imp` will point at a library that won't initially exist and Ninja rightly complains that it is missing and it doesn't know how to create it. If you provide `BUILD_BYPRODUCTS`, it makes sense that the build step shouldn't be empty, so you probably need to do something as a build step, even if it is just a `BUILD_COMMAND` that doesn't actually do anything meaningful.

The following modified definition of `target-ep` should hopefully get things working for you:

```
ExternalProject_Add(target-ep
    INSTALL_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BUILD_DIR}/dummyInstall
    DOWNLOAD_COMMAND <whatever>
    BUILD_BYPRODUCTS /path/to/install/lib/libwhatever.a
    BUILD_COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo_append
    INSTALL_COMMAND ""
    CONFIGURE_COMMAND "")
```

Your original question also creates a dependency on the wrong target. `target-imp` should depend on `target-ep`, but you had `target` depend on `target-ep` instead. The correct dependency can be expressed by this:

```
 add_dependencies(target-imp target-ep)
```

With the `BUILD_BYPRODUCTS` option, Ninja already knows the above dependency, but it is needed for other generators, including make.

You haven't specified what your `<whatever>` download command does, but I'm assuming it is responsible for ensuring that the library will exist at `/path/to/install/lib/libwhatever.a` when it has executed. You could also try making the `DOWNLOAD_COMMAND` empty and putting `<whatever>` as the `BUILD_COMMAND` instead.

To address your specific questions:

> 1. Is this possible at all with Ninja and CMake? (Version is not an issue, I can use the latest CMake if that solves the problem)

Yes, I verified that the approach mentioned above works with Ninja 1.8.2 for a dummy test project on macOS using CMake 3.11.0. I would expect it to work with CMake 3.2 or later (that's when support for the `BUILD_BYPRODUCTS` option was added).

> 2. If there is some way to workaround with explicitly listing BUILD_BYPRODUCTS, is there a way to simply communicate that the entire directory that will get installed is a byproduct? That is, /path/to/install/* is a byproduct?

Unlikely. How would Ninja know what is expected to be in such a directory? The only way to get reliable dependencies would be to explicitly list each file that was expected to be there, which you do using `BUILD_BYPRODUCTS` in your case.

Comment: Adding a missing `BUILD_BYPRODUCTS` solved this issue for me.  Note that you can use `<INSTALL_DIR>`, `<BINARY_DIR>` etc. in `ExternalProject_Add`, these are documented in the ExternalProject_Add docs.

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to download at configuration time, you could follow this [post](https://crascit.com/2015/07/25/cmake-gtest/).  It uses google-test as the example, but I've used the same technique for other dependencies.  Just put your `ExternalProject` code in a separate file, say "CMakeLists.txt.dependencies" and then launch another cmake with `execute_process`.  I use `configure_file` first to inject configuration information into the external project and to copy it into the build tree.

```
configure_file(CMakeLists.txt.dependency.in dependency/CMakeLists.txt)
execute_process(COMMAND "${CMAKE_COMMAND}" -G "${CMAKE_GENERATOR}" .
        WORKING_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/dependency" )
execute_process(COMMAND "${CMAKE_COMMAND}" --build .
        WORKING_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/dependency" )
```

I do this at configuration time so `find_package` and `find_library` commands can work on the dependencies.

And now it doesn't matter what generator you use.

Comment: Very much want to download at build time, not configuration time.