# How can I add a dependency for the ExternalProject mkdir step on a BYPRODUCTS file?

Tags: cmake

I asked this question before ([How to add a dependency on a file for the configure step of ExternalProject_Add in cmake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59341301/how-to-add-a-dependency-on-a-file-for-the-configure-step-of-externalproject-add)) for the configure step.

Unfortunately, the answer that I got there does not work for the 'mkdir' step:

```
ExternalProject_Add_StepDependencies(
  gitache_package_libcwd_r
  download "/opt/gitache/libcwd_r/gitache-lock"
)
```

works fine, but when I use the internal ([Using an ExternalProject download step with Ninja](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50400592/using-an-externalproject-download-step-with-ninja/50548552#50548552)) step 'mkdir':

```
ExternalProject_Add_StepDependencies(
  gitache_package_libcwd_r
  mkdir "/opt/gitache/libcwd_r/gitache-lock"
)
```

I get the error:

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/ExternalProject.cmake:2273 (message):
  External project "gitache_package_libcwd_r" does not have a step "mkdir".
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I stumbled upon the same issue last week. After digging for some time I've found a bug in ExternalProject.cmake module and filed a pull request https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/merge_requests/4640 .

You can patch your local version of that module until it's fixed upstream (Update, fix has been included to version 3.18.0)

Comment: Great job! I completely abandoned using ExternalProject however - it didn't work well enough for me. Besides, I needed things to work during configure time, not build time :p (for my project https://github.com/CarloWood/gitache).

Comment: @CarloWood Actually I use a superbuild pattern and found this approach working really well. In that case everything is done _before_ configure.

Take a look at the links below, hopefully you can find them useful too:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51717207/building-mongo-cxx-driver-using-cmake-externalproject-add/51718660

https://github.com/Sarcasm/cmake-superbuild